# When did Ben Azzai die?

Tags: rabbis, death, martyr

Rabbi Shimeon ben Azzai is listed as having died twice, once as part of the 4 who enter "pardes" [(chagigah 14b](http://images.e-daf.com/DafImg.asp?ID=1556&size=2)) and again as one of the 10 martyrs. Which of these traditions is correct, or is there a way to reconcile both?

Note: the talmud yerushalmi has a variant where ben azzai is not the one who dies, however this is not generally accepted as the proper text. Furthermore there are different lists of the 10 martyrs however ben azzai seems to be on most, if not all of them.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9547/how-did-the-ten-martyrs-actually-die

Comment: This is not one correct from the another, these two different traditions

Comment: @HaimEvgi can you explain your comment please, I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I think this help you , look on the section "מותו של בן עזאי" in the link http://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=1271#

Comment: @HaimEvgi indeed he does attempt to answer this question but I was lost in some of the language and unconvinced by his argument as it pertains to the heichalot. If you could summarize what he says I think it would be a helpful answer though

Comment: Where does it say that he was one of the 10 martyrs?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin see answer in above referenced question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9548/1552

Comment: Note that the legend of the 10 martyrs is somewhat dubious.

Answer (score 5):

This [shiur by Rabbi Ari Kahn](http://www.rabbiarikahn.com/Audio.php?ID=6&Shiur=Aggada) resolves this question by saying that Ben Azzai's death in pardes is not to be taken literally but that he was so spiritually enamored by his experience that he did not have children. Chazal list someone who does not have children as equivalent to a dead person (similar to someone who is blind, penniless etc.)