# Which Tana said the shem hafemorash and why?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shemos-sacred-names, agada-stories-legends, tannaim

I remember learning a gemarah (midrash?) that one of the tanaim (possibly R' Chanina [ben Dosa]) said the shem hameforash explicitly. Can you source this story and explain why the shem hameforash was used?

Comment: It's in one or both of the _piyutim_ we say about the ten martyrs.

Comment: @msh210, in Eleh Ezkera, it is R' Yishmael haKohen haGadol.

Answer (score 4):

The Talmud ([Avodah Zarah 17B](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4010&size=1)-18A) tells us that heaven decreed Chanania ben Teradion's death for using G-d's 42 letter name.

See [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9548/603) as well.