# Did Joseph ever forgive his brothers? Did they request forgiveness?

Tags: history, repentance-teshuvah, yosef

After Yosef revealed himself to his brothers, did the brothers ever ask for Yosef's forgiveness for having sold him into slavery?  And did Yosef ever formally forgive them?  I'm looking for chapter and verse that uses the term "forgive."

Comment: Is this a riddle - i.e. you know of such a chapter and verse and are presenting a challenge to find it? If so, [that's discouraged](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140/2). If not, and if this is indeed an "intriguing question," why are you asking for chapter and verse? If it was explicitly recorded in Tanach, there wouldn't be much intrigue to it, would there?

Comment: Rabbi Emanuel says the answer will be in next week's magazine.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend that you wait until next week's magazine, see what he answers, and post a question here if you believe that something's missing or that there may be alternative answers.

Comment: @BruceJames, did he publish an answer?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, see the comment to Menachem's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Brothers Ask For Forgiveness: [Bereshit 50:16-18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8245/showrashi/true#v16)
- Yosef does not explicitly forgive them. Instead he tells them it was all G-d's plan: [Bereshit 50:19-21](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8245/showrashi/true#v19)
- [Rabbeinu Bechaye says](http://www.torahlab.org/outoftheloop/mechilas_yosef/) that because Yosef never forgave the brothers the [10 Martyrs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9547/how-did-the-ten-martyrs-actually-die) were killed.

Comment: Were they killed because of the brothers' sin being so horrible he couldn't forgive them, or were they killed because Yosef sinned by refusing to forgive them?

Comment: @SethJ: My understanding is that because Yosef never forgave them, the sin was never wiped away and atonement was still needed.

Comment: Your answer is the same as Rabbi Feldman's, published in Mishpacha Feb. 4, 2013 http://www.mishpacha.com/Browse/Article/2928/The-Ten-Most-Answers  -- Best answer!